# UITableView scroll like in Yummly app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm looking for a way to implement scrolling in UITableView similar to what is done in Yummly app, or like google play or whatsapp header, in which the top image sort of hangs or sticks, while the bottom content scrolls over it, until the content catches up with it. 
Meaning, make it so that the cells will not scroll up together, but stick a little, like the section headers do, accept that with section headers the content scrolls below the section, and not on top of it.
Does anyone has any idea how this can be implemented in objective-c?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this project? It might help: https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout

Comment: Yes, it looks pretty much what I was going for, the only problem is that it will require converting my table view to collection view, i was hoping to avoid that, but I will try it out nonetheless and see if it doesn't damage any existing functionality. Thank you very much!

Comment: given answer is useful to you?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked yummly and found the good solution for you i have used this for some of my application/demo as well.

https://github.com/destin-m/parallax_tableview

Please let me know if you require any other modification as well.

Regards.